# Run terminal command within sandbox

Tags: macos, cocoa, finder, nstask, appstore-sandbox

I wrote a Mac app that turns Desktop icons visible/invisible. I use `NSTask` to run a terminal command to reset the `Finder`:

```
- (void)killFinder
{
    NSTask *killFinderTask = [[NSTask alloc]init];
    NSArray *killFinderArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Finder", nil];
    [killFinderTask setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/killall"];
    [killFinderTask setArguments:killFinderArray];
    [killFinderTask launch];
    [killFinderTask waitUntilExit];
}
```

Before turning on Sandboxing, it runs alright. When I turn on Sandboxing, a message in console said:

```
killall: warning: kill -TERM 46676: Operation not permitted
```

My app still runs but the result is not correct. The part which reset the `Finder` is not run. How do I circumvent this issue so that I can still use Sandboxing but the task is still run?

Comment: I don't think you can.  At least I hope you can't, else it's not much of a sandbox.

Comment: Your app can't reach out of sandbox, that is why you can't. Even if you achieve this your app will be rejected.

Comment: Are you submitting your app to Mac app store ?

Comment: I wish to but it seems like it is not possible. So I can only distribute outside Mac App Store.

Comment: By the way, this was never a good way to restart the Finder. You could have sent the same signal that `killall` would programmatically using `kill()`. You could use `NSRunningApplication` to `terminate` it. You could use Apple Script to quit it. No need to invoke an external program. Although these are also going to be restricted by the sandbox, they are at least more likely to have an official entitlement to enable it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSUserScriptTask` to run the Script.

The script file must be placed (by the user) in the `NSApplicationScriptsDirectory` to be run outside of the Sandbox.